# Transfer Data by matching Header

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Backend raw output data set, which consists of multiple columns with some of them being empty except of the header.

I would like to transfer this data into another worksheet, let's call it Backend - processed. In this worksheet, I would prepare a header row, which consists of some of the headers included in the original data set. There won't be any new headers in the processed worksheet (so basically headers(processed) is a subset of headers(raw output)).

Once, I used to solve this problem with a function (Index & Match), but with growing raw data sets, this became suboptimal from a performance perspective.

Since then, I've been reading up on VBA codes and this is what I came up with until now:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range, msg As String
    With Sheets("Backend - raw").Range("4:4").CurrentRegion
        For Each r In Sheets("Backend - processed").Range("b7:t7")
            Set c = .Rows(1).Find(r.Value, , , xlWhole, , 0)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                .Columns(c.Column).Copy
                r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Else
                msg = msg & vbLf & r.Value
            End If
        Next
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

The Range 4:4 is where the headers of the original raw data output are found. Range b7:t7 is where the headers of the processed data table are found.

Being a total beginner at VBA, I'm quite happy that it works, but still think that there is a huge margin for improvement:

1) It's still pretty slow, taking about 10 seconds to complete 40x500 arrays.
2) I don't know how to make it stop looking for the next header, if the last header was blank (end of range b7:t7)
3) I'm very much open to new/better approaches to tackle this issue.

Comment: A quick win is to include `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of your code and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end. This avoids Excel having to update the screen display

Comment: Thank you Miguel! I added it and gained some seconds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching, copying and pasting can be quite time consuming affairs. You'd probably be better off reading the headers just once into some kind of stored list (a `Collection` would work well for you because it could store the column number as its value and the header text as its key.

Given that you are only copying and pasting values (ie you don't need to pass cell formatting into your processed sheet) then reading the values into an array and then writing that array to the sheet will be quicker.

The code below is an example of that, but I'm sure with more thought it could be made even quicker (for example by discarding a header from the collection once it's been used, or not having to find the last row number for every individual column).

```
    Dim rawSht As Worksheet
    Dim procSht As Worksheet
    Dim headers As Collection
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim v As Variant

    Set rawSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend - raw")
    Set procSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Backend - processed")

    Set headers = New Collection
    For c = 1 To rawSht.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        headers.Add c, rawSht.Cells(4, c).Text
    Next

    For c = 2 To 20
        rawCol = headers(procSht.Cells(7, c).Text)
        v = rawSht.Range(rawSht.Cells(5, rawCol), rawSht.Cells(Rows.Count, rawCol).End(xlUp)).Value2
        procSht.Cells(8, c).Resize(UBound(v, 1)).Value = v
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will try to implement it soon and will let you know how it worked out. Good thing is, I learned about collections, which I apparently missed out somehow.

Comment: Your approach can actually be even faster than arrays (with a few adjustments), as in [this setup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32791938/4914662). The slowest part is what you already mentioned - updating the range

Comment: @CDC, No problem. Have a read of handling the case where a key doesn't exist in the collection - throws an error. Most people try to catch that error to handle item doesn't exist.

Comment: @Ambie: I tried some error handling in your code. I was looking at the possibility of inserting a column in the output table, with a header which was not found in the input table. I came up with this solution `

Answer (score 1):

This is using arrays (40 cols x 1000 rows in 0.03125 sec)

```
Option Explicit

Sub testArr()
    Const HDR1 As Long = 4  'header row on sheet 1
    Const HDR2 As Long = 7  'header row on sheet 2

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ur1 As Range, vr1 As Variant, c1 As Long, c2 As Long, r As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, ur2 As Range, vr2 As Variant, msg As String, t As Double

    t = Timer
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Backend - raw")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Backend - processed")

    Set ur1 = ws1.UsedRange
    Set ur2 = ws2.UsedRange.Rows(ws2.UsedRange.Row - HDR2 + 1)
    Set ur2 = ur2.Resize(ur1.Row + ur1.Rows.Count - HDR1 + 1)

    vr1 = ur1   'copy from Range to array
    vr2 = ur2

    For c1 = 1 To UBound(vr1, 2)
        For c2 = 1 To UBound(vr2, 2)
            If vr1(1, c1) = vr2(1, c2) Then
                For r = 2 To UBound(vr1, 1)
                    vr2(r, c2) = vr1(r, c1)
                Next
                Exit For
            Else
                msg = msg & vbLf & vr1(HDR1, c1)
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ur2 = vr2   'copy from array back to Range

    Debug.Print "testArr duration: " & Timer - t & " sec"
End Sub
```

Comment: Gets my vote for reading into an array and looping through that. With big ranges, it's so much quicker.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I chose the @Ambie apporach just because it doesn't re-convert my destination Excel-Table back to a range (I use Excel-Table references for further analysis).